# Author Affiliation superscripts not labeling properly in title

Tags: elsarticle, addresses, author

I am having an infuriating time trying to get the numbering of my affiliations correct using the Elsevier article class.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\journal{Prestigious Journal}

\title{Baldrick has a Clever Title}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Add Authors
\author[add1]{Author1 \corref{cor1}}
\ead{author1@email.com}

\author[add1]{Author2}
\ead{author2@email.com}

\author[add2]{Author3}
\ead{author3@email.com}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address[add1]{School of Turnip Engineering}
\address[add2]{School of Sausage Engineering}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{linenumbers}
\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{abstract}
%% Text of abstract
Turnips go well with sausages.\\ 

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Turnips \sep More Turnips 
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

[image: Code output with mis-labelled affiliations]

The superscripts are wrong (but at least sequentially correct). I have tried many variations. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you expect (what would be right)? Starting with `a` or something different?

Comment: Which Tex compiler and version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Numbering seems to go back to normal, if one does not use `\begin{frontmatter}...\end{frontmatter}`

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\journal{Prestigious Journal}

\title{Baldrick has a Clever Title}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Add Authors
\author[add1]{Author1 \corref{cor1}}
\ead{author1@email.com}

\author[add1]{Author2}
\ead{author2@email.com}

\author[add2]{Author3}
\ead{author3@email.com}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address[add1]{School of Turnip Engineering}
\address[add2]{School of Sausage Engineering}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{linenumbers}
%\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{abstract}
%% Text of abstract
Turnips go well with sausages.\\ 

\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Turnips \sep More Turnips 
\end{keyword}

%\end{frontmatter}
\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I may just have to live without my frontmatter cover sheet.

Comment: @BrianFreeman Or you can ask a question about your cover sheet. If we would know how it should look like, there might be an alternative